# SQL Server do declare statements in a loop cause significant speed issues and if so how can I resolve?

Tags: sql-server

I have a function which is called many times. The function has several DECLARE statements in the body of it.

I'm wondering what the impact of this is if the function is called say, 100,000 times, and if there is a way to make the declaration global such that the same variable is re-used each time rather than being allocated/deallocated constantly.

I might be thinking too much like a regular programmer in the way that SQL works, but ultimately I need to streamline it as much as possible to improve performance as currently it's shockingly bad.

Comment: It's in a table-valued function. I don't know what that means unfortunately.

Comment: If you post the function, you might get help converting it from a multi-statement table-valued function to an inline table-valued function, which has a much better chance of being optimized.

Comment: You need to include the code of your function, and then ask a more specific question. A vague description of the code and a "Is there a way I can improve this code I'm not showing you?" isn't really an answerable question here.

Comment: It is shockingly bad becasue you are looping which is something that you should almost never do. You need to think in terms of sets not indivudal records. A function called 100,000 times is a far worse performer than one called once. Your function in all lielihood needs to be re-written to perform correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I think the optimisation overall is a separate much bigger question. I was just interested specifically if you can avoid declaring a variable within a function that is gonna be called lots of times, appreciate the enthusiasm though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL Server performance impact of DECLARE is minimal. Unmeasurable. Things that affect performance in SQL are data access paths (ie. indexes) and execution plans. Post your exact DDL schema (including all indexes), the statement you run and the captured execution plan.

Comment: Well they can definitely indirectly affect things, for example if the DECLAREs are the only thing standing between a multi-statement TVF and an inline TVF...

Comment: Thanks, that pretty much sums it up :)